# Closing bootstrap 4 modal window prevents scrolling of a modal window underneath the closed window

Tags: bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 modal. I have a script that opens a modal windows via a data toggle
When the modal window opens I have a picture that can be clicked to open another modal window that displays a larger image.

When I close the second modal window I can't scroll the first modal window. When I attempt to scroll the first modal window the page behind the modal scrolls. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong.

```
//DATA TOGGLE
<a href="#" class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#spinaltherapy">Test</a>

//FIRST MODAL
<div class="modpos">
  <div class="modal fade" id="spinaltherapy">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="margin-top: 55px">
      <div class="modal-content"> 
    
    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Test</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <section class="left-col">
        <p>Test text </p>
        <div class="two-div">
          <ul class="div-list1">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <liItem 2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!--- Start One third -->
      <div class="clearfix-padding"></div>
      <section class="one-third-padding">
        <h4>Test header text</h4>
        <div class="spinal-pic3">
        <img src="img/pics/equine-hydrotherapy.png">
        <div class="three-pic-enlarge2">Click to enlarge</div>
        </div>
        <p  class="spinal-col">Test text.</p>
      </section>
          </div>
    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

//SECOND MODAL

<div class="modal fade" id="imagepreviewspinal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">              
      <div class="modal-body">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <img src="" class="imagepreviewspinal" style="width: 200%;" >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

//CLICK FUNCTION
$(function() {
        $('.spinal-pic3').on('click', function() {
            $('.imagepreviewspinal').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
            $('#imagepreviewspinal').modal('show');   
        });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I now have it working using the following script.

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  if ($('.modal:visible').length > 0) {
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
  }
});
```